# Symbol for "corresponds to" (equals sign with hat)

Tags: symbols

Recently in some LaTeX documentation I noticed that there is a special LaTeX command for the symbol meaning "corresponds to", which is similar to an equal sign with a hat on top. `\hat{=}` or `\widehat{=}` both do not give satisfying results (my personal view). Unfortunately, I cannot remember which documentation it was! Does anyone know the command or the documentation where to find it?

The symbol I am looking for:

[image: The symbol I am looking for]

PS: I have already tried [detexify](http://detexify.kirelabs.org/classify.html) but it didn't produce anything useful! Also, browsing [the comprehensive LaTeX symbol list](ftp://ftp.tu-chemnitz.de/pub/tex/info/symbols/comprehensive/symbols-a4.pdf) wasn't successful.

Comment: `$\cong$` might be what you want. Other related symbols are `\simeq`, `\sim`, `\approx`.  There is a symbol bible out on the web called symbols-A4.pdf.  Very useful.

Comment: In addition to trying the above, could you perhaps draw what you want and upload it here? (Carefully drawing it on paper and then taking a picture is probably the easiest way.) Mathematical notation varies greatly from region to region; e.g. my training urges me to use something similar to `\func`.

Comment: `\stackrel{\frown}{=}`

Comment: I have added a picture. @hpesoj626 I remeber that it was a special command (like `\cong` for example) not a composition of different commands. I know that that I can define a command myself but I want to know what that command was ;-)

Comment: Not sure why I read your question and saw "tilde" instead of "hat" in my first comment, but the symbol bible is still useful.

Comment: Since you even linked to the Comprehensive LaTeX symbol list: Table 76, second column, last row on page 32 ;-)

Comment: I addition to @mafp's command `\mathrel{\widehat{=}}` might help you. It would help us, if you discribe, **what** is not good with the commands you found.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equals_sign says it's ≘ so `\stackrel{\frown}{=}` can be an option, too. But @mafp is correct. `mathabx` indeed provides `\corresponds`

Comment: I think we can close this as a duplicate. But I would suggest that you don't delete this question since other readers might search for the same symbol.

Comment: With `\stackrel{\frown}{=}` the hat is not square but round. With `\mathrel{\widehat{=}}` or `\widehat{=}` the distance between the hat and the = is to big (in my eyes). `\cooresponds` does look good but it needs the `mathabx` package. Loading it I get an error `\leftmoon already defined` without having done anything with `\leftmoon` ... I am quite certain that that symbol I saw didn't need any special package. But maybe I was dreaming :-) @mafp Sorry, apparently I overlooked this in the list!

Comment: `\mathrel{\widehat{=}}` and `\widehat{=}` are actually the same as they will produce the same symbol. The only difference (at least to my knowledge) is, that the former tells tex it is a relation symbol which results in more free space in front and behind it. What ever symbol you use at the end: it might be a good idea to put it into `\mathrel{}`for that particular reason.

Comment: this is unicode x+2259, and as such should be present in a font that supports the unicode symbols.

Comment: I've 'reverse duped' here: there is a newer question with a wider range of answers

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try this.  Of course, the parameters can be adjusted to change vertical separation height or horizontal width of wedge relative to = sign, or aspect ratio of wedge.  Note that the appearance of this is not quite the same as `\hateq` cited in comments above, but better conforms to the symbol illustrated by the questioner.

**REVISED SOLUTION** eliminated use of `array` to make space around `\equalhat` compatible with `\mathrel`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{scalerel,stackengine,amsmath}
\newcommand\equalhat{\mathrel{\stackon[1.5pt]{=}{\stretchto{%
    \scalerel*[\widthof{=}]{\wedge}{\rule{1ex}{3ex}}}{0.5ex}}}}
\begin{document}
\[
x^2 \equalhat \ensurestackMath{\Centerstack[c]{a b c}}
\]

\begin{align}
a &\equalhat b \\
a &= b
\end{align}
\end{document}
```

[image]

**ORIGINAL SOLUTION**

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{scalerel,amssymb}

\newcommand\equalhat{%
\let\savearraystretch\arraystretch
\renewcommand\arraystretch{0.3}
\begin{array}{c}
\stretchto{
    \scalerel*[\widthof{=}]{\wedge}
    {\rule{1ex}{3ex}}%
}{0.5ex}\\ 
=%
\end{array}
\let\arraystretch\savearraystretch
}

\begin{document}

$x^2 \equalhat \begin{array}{c}a\\b\\c\end{array}$

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: What I don't like with this solution is that  `$a \equalhat b$` and `$a = b$` have different spacing. Can this be fixed?

Comment: @bers That is a problem with the `array` environment, as I understand it.  I will give thought to fixing that (after I get back from next meeting).

Comment: @bers One quick and simple fix is to edit the `\equalhat` definition by adding a `\!` at the very beginning and very end of the definition.

Comment: Sure, this work, but rather imperfectly (if what one is after is alignment with the regular `=` character).

Comment: @bers I am not sure that the quick fix is imperfect, but in any event, I have revised the solution to eliminate the use of `array`.